# Image slider Safari issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've just completed a website i'm working on but i'm having an issue with my image slider in Safari. It seems to be fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Here is the url: http://www.paulcrookconsultancy.com/

This is the code i'm using:

```
var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
var images = $('ul.images li');
var lastElem = triggers.length-1;

triggers.first().addClass('active');
images.hide().first().show();

function sliderResponse(target) {
images.fadeOut(500).eq(target).fadeIn(500);
triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
}

triggers.click(function() {
  if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
      target = $(this).index();
      sliderResponse(target);
      resetTiming();
  }
});

function sliderTiming() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
    sliderResponse(target);
}

var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
    function resetTiming() {
    clearInterval(timingRun);
    timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.mask {
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
background:#eee;
}

ul.images {
position:relative;
z-index:2;
top:0px;
left:0px;
height:100%;
}

ul.images li { 
    position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
bottom:0;
}

ul.images li img {
position:relative;
    width:100%;
height:100%;
}

ul.images li h2, ul.images li h3 {
position:absolute;
margin:0;
line-height:50px;
padding:0 15px;
width:100%;

}

ul.images li h2 {
bottom:50px;
color:#fff;
font-weight:300;
background:url(../images/imgSliderBack.png);
}

ul.images li h3 {
bottom:0;
color:#97835f;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:400;
background:#000;
}

ul.triggers li {
float:left;
margin:15px 5px;
width:10px;
height:10px;
border-radius:5px;
background:#192545;
cursor:pointer;
}

ul.triggers li.active {background:#97835f;}

ul.triggers li:hover {background:#000;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mask">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <ul class="images">
        <li>
          <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Business Solutions"/>
          <h2>Are you short of time?</h2>
          <h3>Find out more about our services and how they will benefit your business.</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Financial and Business Advisor"/>
          <h2>Do you know who to trust with your finances and business planning?</h2>
          <h3>Discover what previous clients think of our service.</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Trusted Advisor"/>
          <h2>Do you need a trusted advisor?</h2>
          <h3>Paul Crook has over 35 years experience working in the industry.</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt="Business Growth"/>
          <h2>Do you want to grow your business and make it more efficient?</h2>
          <h3>Lets work together to see your business benefit.</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

If there was a way for me to have the h2 and h3 tags fade in when the parent img fades in, this should sort it - how would i go about doing that?

Comment: I don't see anything strange. Whats the issue?

Comment: The image sliders first image does not load correctly then it 'settles down' once the second slide kicks in. Try reloading the page and see if that causes it to happen.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it has something to do with this line:

```
images.hide().first().show();
```

Try this instead:

```
images.not(":eq(0)").hide();
```

Comment: still not working correctly. Do you know how i would go about making the headings css display:none and then have them fade In when the img shows?

Comment: Ik think the problem is the width of ul.images.
Can you give a 100% width?