# Fonts thinning in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

Since adding my jQuery image slider i have noticed that in Safari the fonts are 'thinning' / not rendering properly. I have tried adding:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
```

But this is not working. Does anyone have any other ideas?

URL: http://www.paulcrookconsultancy.com/

The code for the image slider is here: [Image slider Safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326576/image-slider-safari-issue/25328363#25328363)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try.

Instead of font-weight: 300 use font-weight: bolder or extra bold

Your CSS is different than this you can also try in the body

```
  body {
   -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
   }
```

Comment: Which did the trick both or one? Click the arrow above the 0 to vote me up if that works for you. Thanks and glad to help.

Comment: -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; Did it for me. :) Thanks again.